# Cannot understand the new class feature of ES2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having a difficulty to understand 
how the class feature works out.

Can you super simplify it to me the following snippet
with simple everyday words?

I really find it hard to grasp the whole thing.

That super function looks very weird, also.

Thank you in advance.

```
class Dessert {
  constructor(calories = 250) {
    this.calories = calories;
  }
}

class IceCream extends Dessert {
  constructor(flavor, calories, toppings = []) {
    super(calories);
    this.flavor = flavor;
    this.toppings = toppings;
  }
  addTopping(topping) {
    this.toppings.push(topping);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you understand how constructors, prototypes and inheritance worked in ES5?

Comment: What is "the whole thing", or are you only asking about `super`? Did you read [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)?

Comment: Hello @Bergi I understand the concept of the prototype chaining and the inheritance on ES5

But I'm new in ES6 some features look very weird to me.

Comment: It's basically just a new syntax for the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think easiest to understand is just to create a new instance of IceCream:

```
var iceCream = new IceCream('vanilla'); 
console.log(iceCream) // IceCream {calories: 250, flavor: "vanilla", toppings: Array(0)}
```

As you see, you wasn't needed to pass calories value - `super` calls parent class and takes that value.

When you have a constructor function, and instantiate new instance `constructor` method being fired first, to collect properties as you describe in it.

Comment, please, if something is unclear. I would love to provide more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot.

What if you want to set a different value for the calories?
Lets say 500.

The super() will set the value for the calories?

Comment: You can set it either by instantiating instance `var iceCream = new IceCream('vanilla', 500);` or later changing calories value `iceCream.calories = 500`.

Comment: I see. I'm getting a better picture of it now.

super is for accessing properties or methods from the object that it inherits. 

Thanks a lot